# Laravel - Class/Model not found

Tags: php, laravel, models

Initially, this code worked, but it doesn't work anymore. I don't know what is causing the issue.

The error is :

```
FatalErrorException in AdminController.php line 64:
Class 'App\Category' not found
```

`AdminController` code is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Category;
use View;   

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function article_get()
    {
        $categories = Category::latest()->get();
        return View::make('create.article')->with('categories',$categories);
    }
}
```

My model Category is located at `App/Models/Category.php`.

What I've tried:

1. Change from `use App\Category;` to `use Category`, to `use \Category`, to `use App\Models\Category`.
2. `composer dump-autoload`.

A few hours ago I had a working project, but now my models are not found.

Comment: What is your namespace in `Category.php`?

Comment: @brokenbinary, namespace App. Also, if I create a model at 'App/Category.php', it will be fine and working.

Answer (score 2):

Because Laravel uses [PSR-4 autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), you need to make sure your namespaces match the real directory structure.

You say that your `Category` model is located at `App/Models/Category.php` so its namespace should be `App\Models`. Then, in your controllers you would `use App\Models\Category`.

Answer (score 2):

I had also faced the same error when Models are called inside Controllers or  Seeders.

**The best solution is to import your Model inside the Controllers.**

- Add the below line at the top of your AdminController.

  `use App\Models\Category`

This is applicable for all Classes where you try to call your models.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this and it must work:

```
use App\Models\Category
```

and make sure that the model Category is inside a folder named Models.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine.
May be it has an issue with namespace in Category model.

if you use this code for Category Model in your AdminController controller:

```
use App\Models\Category;
```

then your Category model itself has this namespace

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Check if your model namespace is still there or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
App\Models\Category
```

PLease Check This twoThings

1.Importing `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

2,Check Controller Letter is in Upper Or LowerCase
like this

```
use App\models\Category----->❌❌❌
use App\Models\Category----->✅✅✅
```

Answer (score -1):

use App\Models\Category

//check your models is capital or small letter sometimes issue like that is a big problem

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to add some supporting information to your post that explains what your code does. There appears to be issues with formatting in your answer as well, take a look at stackoverflow.com/editing-help